# Css scale animation not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using the following to give the text a sort of pulsating effect, but the animation doesn't seem to work in chrome. What am I doing wrong?

```
.item{
    -webkit-animation: caMenuTextOut 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: caMenuTextOut 600ms ease-in-out;
    animation: caMenuTextOut 600ms ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes caMenuTextOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome doesn't support standard animations yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=animations).  Use the vendor prefix: `@-webkit-keyframes`.  You can have this at the same time as `@keyframes`, but you have to declare the entire thing twice, unfortunately.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/85hE5/